# Healthcheck for multi region Lambda behind ALB talking to SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, health-check

We have a lambda defined in multiple regions running in active/standby mode.  Switching requires a manual Route53 update.

The Lambda basically just pushes a message onto an SNS topic.

Looking at switching to an active/active configuration.  But trying to figure out how to set up a healthcheck.

In the examples I've found online, the `/healthcheck` lambda code is simply returning a status as set in an environment variable, for ease of testing.  I suppose that makes sense, but is there anything else the I should consider?  For instance, if the lambda was talking to DDB, a deep healthcheck would confirm that DDB is healthy.  But is there anything I can do to check SNS other than actually publishing some dummy message of some sort?

Furthermore, I'm a bit confused about differences between

- pointing the ALB to the healthcheck, and having the R53 Alias records doing a `Evaluate Target Health`
- Having the healthcheck endpoint specified on the R53 CNAME records.

Is there some difference?  Should I do one or the other?  Or both?